# What adjectives should be used in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

> The population of Cairo had become too ____.

Which answer is correct? Large, small, big, wide. I say too large but not sure.

Comment: Large or small are adjectives of size, applicable to a population. The population of Cairo had become too large for the amount of drinking water available; the population of Cairo had become too small to provide enough men for the army.

Comment: Also dense or sparse regarding the number of people per square mile(s)/kilometer(s).

Comment: There is no way of knowing what you want to say. It could be "too large", "too big" or "too small" but it could also be "... too angry" or "too happy" or almost anything.  Please [edit] to explain what meaning you want to express.

Answer (score 1):

"Wide" is not appropriate, because it refers to a particular dimensionality that does not apply to a population. "Small", "large", and "big" would all work, although "small" obviously has the opposite meaning.